# Pass UITableView scrolling gesture to superview UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `SuperUITableView` as the main superview; inside that superview, I have another UITableView called `SubUITableView`.

I want to pass the scrolling gesture from the subview (`SubUITableView`) to the superview (`SuperUITableView`)

If the question is not clear, kindly ask me anything in the comments instead of downvoting.

Comment: What is the purpose of having a TableView with another TableView as subview? What are you trying to achieve, maybe there is more efficient way?

Comment: Actually, this is nested UICollectionViews with UITableViews task. In this scenario, I'm doing it this way, because inside the SubUITableView the data might change which will affect the number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

UITableViews will confirms to scrollViewDidScroll delegate.

Inside the delegate of inner tableView, you just programmically scroll super tableView.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    UIScrollView *parentScrollView = (scrollView == self.tableView1) ? self.tableView2 : self.tableView1;
    [otherScrollView setContentOffset:[scrollView contentOffset] animated:NO];
}
```